# Xcode consistently fails to launch app on device: "Unknown packet reply: "timeout" to environment packet."

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4

Since upgrading to Xcode 4.2 I've regularly encountered an error where attempting to debug an app fails with the message "Unknown packet reply: "timeout" to environment packet." Restarting the device does not consistently solve the problem (though it sometimes does), nor does restarting Xcode or rebooting the development machine. Cleaning and recompiling also does not fix the problem.

It's not limited to the project; once it happens I can no longer launch *any* apps through Xcode.

The device is an iPad running iOS 4.3.5; the development machine is a Macbook running Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have *no idea* what was causing this before, but I haven't seen it since upgrading to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4.1 so I'm answering the question to mark it closed.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't see similar reports. I would suspect the usb cable at this point.

Comment: As did I, initially -- but I get the same error with multiple cables, and don't get it with other devices on the same cables. The iPad in question is a development device (that's its purpose in life) -- I'm beginning to suspect that it's a device problem, but I've no idea how to diagnose that. This isn't a constant problem, just one that's becoming increasingly frequent.

Comment: I had this issue, switching Lightning cables solved it for me.