# Xcode7 watchOS2 not debuggable on Simulator

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, watchkit, watchos-2, xcode7-beta2

My Watch OS2 app is running on Simulator okay but all the breakpoints I set in awakeWithContext, willActivate ... even when they have run and produced the result, the breakpoints are not hit.

In Debug Navigator, all I can see is "Installing and Waiting to Attach":

[image: Illustration]

How to get these breakpoints hit for the Watch app?

The breakpoints for iPhone app hit normally when I run the iPhone app.

I have done many things - restart the Xcode, reset both Simulators, uninstall Watch app inside iPhone Simulator ... Nothing works, still "installing and waiting to attach"

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

P.S: [Here is a relevant question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257474/xcode-7-0-beta-fails-to-launch-a-watchos-2-app-on-apple-watch?rq=1)

Comment: Have you tried to attach the process manually?  Debug -> attach to process and choose your extension

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Xcode 7 beta3, and this is not happening anymore. Now the breakpoints are hit. 
Cheers!